# Converting `trollius` to `asyncio`

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have a project that I want, for now, to make compatible with both `trollius` and `asyncio`. Currently, it only supports `trollius`. It defines coroutines and uses them as generators.

I have this peace of a code

```
result = yield From(item.create())
raise Return(result)
```

The `create` method is defined as `@trollius.coroutine` and it send some Protobuf 2 messages. I can make a small cheat with

```
try:
    import asyncio
except ImportError:
    import trollius as asyncio
    from trollius import From
```

and then redefine `@trollius.coroutine` to `@asyncio.coroutine`, but `yield from` can be a problem. I have read that, from Python 3.8, coroutines will be deprecated. Is there another way to define an asynchronous coroutine and satisfy both `trollius` and `asyncio`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a dead-end. Even if you manage to bridge the impedance mismatch between trollius and asyncio, you will still be left with the differences between Python 2 and Python 3, such as Unicode handling and different library ecosystem. If you really need to support Python 2, can you get away with simply using threads for concurrency?

Answer (score 3):

No way, sorry.

[trollius](https://github.com/vstinner/trollius) is a dead project for 3 years exactly for the same reason: it is impossible to get a *complex* code executed seamlessly on both trollius and asyncio.

Trollius was an interesting try but it has failed.